# Examples of strongly convex loss functions

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, convex

This is a reference request.
Strong convexity of the loss function is often used in theoretical analyses of convex optimisation for machine learning. My question is, are there important / widely used loss functions (or cost functions) being used in machine learning in practice? I know of the logistic loss for classification, and the square loss for regression. Are there any others?

Answer (score 1):

Another example is Hinge loss used in SVM.

Related [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222585/what-are-the-impacts-of-choosing-different-loss-functions-in-classification-to-a)

Also, L1 related loss: least absolute loss.

Combination between L1 and L2 regularization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization).